# Error: Could not find MIME for Buffer <null> while using Jimp to save the buffer of cv.Mat()

Tags: javascript, opencv, jimp

Here is the snippet of my code which produce the error:

```
let mat = cv.Mat.zeros(cnn_size, cnn_size, 3);
savepath = "path/to/saved/image.jpg"
let bf = Buffer.from(mat.data);
Jimp.read(bf).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data.resize(cnn_size, cnn_size).write(savepath);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Running the code caused this error: (node:2152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not find MIME for Buffer `<null>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with a project I was working on. A combination of axios and jimp.read worked for me.

```
axios({
method: 'get',
url: failingImageUrl,
responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})
.then(function ({data: imageBuffer}) {
 return jimp.read(imageBuffer)
})
```

Source https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp/issues/775#issuecomment-521938738

Comment: thanks at @gbengaoyetade this works for me